# Soap webservice in android is not working

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I have soap web service url. The same url is working with login method in one android application, I am able to logged in to the app. When I use same url and different login method in my second app I am getting

*org.ksoap2.transport.HttpResponseException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 403* exception.

My soap webservice url is working fine on browser and postman. My url is http not https.

Comment: `403` means forbidden access, you probably misconfigured connection somehow. if you are using http (without s) then maybe you need [network configuration file](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config), which allows such connections? (especially `cleartextTrafficPermitted` flag)

Comment: @snachmsm I have provided cleartextTrafficPermitted with <network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="false">http://example.example1.com/</domain>
    </domain-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>